Can't boot into Ubuntu 22.04, No space for dpkg
I am running a dual-boot setup with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11 on a Dell Inspiron, with the Grub bootloader.
Recently, I tried to boot up my computer for the first time in a little while (roughly a month). I mention the time because I do not remember if I installed any new updates prior to rebooting recently. To be clear, I have successfully booted into Ubuntu with this setup for the past year.
The operating system hangs but never boots, or shows a handful of ACPI BIOS Errors (Could not resolve symbol ... Aborting method ...) and then hangs. This occurs when I try using Linux 6.5.0-35-generic or 6.5.0-28-generic.
If I add acpi=off to my boot options, I get a whole slew of errors (IRQ, Intel ISH, hdaudio, Bluetooth) and then it still just hangs after a while. I booted into Windows 11 (which works perfectly) and installed a new UEFI update (BIOS Version 1.30.0). Secure Boot is off.
Updating the BIOS did not change anything. I have tried to go through all of the Advanced Options but nothing seems to help. I was unable to run dpkg because there was not enough free space, and running clean did not make enough space for it.
Any thoughts on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated, OR if there's any way I can recover my files from the device (like to an external hard drive) even if I can't get back into it.

df -h;df -i please after choosing an older kernel in grub menu.

@nobody I cannot boot into the older kernel, either.

"I was unable to run dpkg because there was not enough free space" Your Ubuntu partition is full. That's likely why you are also having trouble booting. Boot into a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment and use that to clear space on your partition. Look for user files (like movies and other media). Look for runaway log files in /var/log/. clean rarely helps -- packages are much too small. Use the Search box at the top of the page -- how to clear a full partition or disk has been asked and answered many times.

@user535733 was right, the OS wouldn't boot because the partition was full. The helpful tip was to "boot into a LiveUSB's 'Try Ubuntu' environment and use that to clear space on your partition".
I'll leave this up in case anyone else has this happen and has similar difficulty figuring out what's actually wrong.
